# security token problem with ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, security, csrf

when building apps I use a token to prevent attacks on the forms

each time a form is rendered it gets a new **ONE TIME** security token that i include in the form as a hidden field. this token is also stored in the session.

when the form is sent, the token is verified against the token in the session to make sure the form is legit. This works great for standard pages.

**PROBLEM**
when using Ajax to send forms, there may be multiple on a page, once you send one of these forms, the token is then invalid for the others as its a one time token.

does anyone have advise for this? or is it secure enough to generate one token per session and just use that instead of invalidating the token each time a form is sent?

Comment: What happens if I open some of your normal forms in separate tabs? Do you keep multiple valid tokens in the session at once?

Comment: thats a very good question, to be honest im trying to figure out how to do one time tokens, currently my token is good for the session, i guess your question points out that ajax is not the only problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow your current approach, you can generate a security token each time you do a an AJAX request, return it in the AJAX response, and inject it into the hidden when you get it.
However, I'd go rethinking your current approach for security tokens. [Here](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) you have some tips about that in the OSWAP wiki.

Comment: I was not aware of this library, but seems to be a good option, thanks for that. In my opinion, I would not go doing that work, It's better to delegate it to a library, and later, if needed, build it.

Comment: the library you suggest won't help you with client-side forms/ajax requests though, because it just rewrites the forms that are generated server-side with PHP.